# how to output a character to a file multiple times in matlab using fprintf

Tags: linux, matlab, for-loop, octave, printf

Greets all

I'm trying to output a character (a parenthesis) **')'** to a file multiple times based on the length of a for loop.
Example:

```
num1=23;
for i=1 length(array) 
     fprintf(fid,strcat(num2str(num1)),')')
end
```

output to the file would be **23))))))**

the length of the array is 6 it should print 6 parenthesis **))))))** to the file

I'm using octave/matlab on linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use repmat, for example: `string = repmat(')',1,6)` will produce `))))))` and store it in variable `string`. And you can then append this string before `fprintf` into a file.

```
string = repmat(')',1,6)
fprintf(fid,[num2str(num1) string])
```

Btw, the string concatenate in matlab is done much nicer using: `str = ['str1' 'str2' 'str3']` than strcat.

Comment: I found out you can also do it this way
paraStr=[];
for zz=1:length(array_combined)
 paraStr=[paraStr ')'];
end